# Code inside if statements won't execute, why won't post and get methods set?

Tags: php, forms, post, get, isset

Here's my code, at first I had an undefined index notice for `postimg` (the input variable in the form) in the `foreach()` loop, I got rid of the notice by checking if `postimg` was set, however now my posts and images won't show up, I debugged my code to find that nothing in the if statements were being executed, why is post and get not getting set?

```
<?php 
include("connect.php"); 
include("check.php");
include("image.php");
$postbody = "";
$posts = "";
//$postimg = "";      
if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
    //  $time = connect::query('SELECT posted_at FROM dry_posts WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['id']));
    //$postimg = $_POST['postimg']
    //if(isset($_POST['postimg'])) {
           //$id = connect::query('SELECT id FROM dry_posts WHERE id=:id', array(':id'=>$_GET['id']));
            if ($_FILES['postimg']['size'] == 0) {
                $postbody = $_POST['postbody'];
                $loggedInUserId = check::isLoggedIn();
                if (strlen($postbody) > 160 || strlen($postbody) < 1) {
                    die('Incorrect length!');
                }

                connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, :postbody, NOW(), 0)', array(':postbody'=>$postbody));
            } 
            else {
                //$postid = Post::createImgPost($_POST['postbody']);
                if (strlen($postbody) > 160) {
                    die('Incorrect length!');
                }

                connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, :postbody, NOW(), 0)', array(':postbody'=>$postbody));
                    $postid = connect::query('SELECT id FROM dry_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1');
                    Image::uploadImage('postimg', "UPDATE dry_posts SET postimg=:postimg WHERE id=:postid", array(':postid'=>$postid));
                }
            }

            if (isset($_GET['postid'])) {
                //Post::likePost($_GET['postid']);
                if (!connect::query('SELECT post_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']))) {
                    connect::query('UPDATE dry_posts SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                    connect::query('INSERT INTO post_likes VALUES (null, :postid)', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                } 
                else {
                    connect::query('UPDATE dry_posts SET likes=likes-1 WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                    connect::query('DELETE FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                }
            }

            // $posts = Post::displayPosts();
            $dbposts = connect::query('SELECT * FROM dry_posts ORDER BY id DESC');
            $posts = "";

            if(isset($_FILE['postimg'])){ 
                foreach($dbposts as $p) {
                    if (!connect::query('SELECT post_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$p['id']))) {
                        $posts .="<img src='".$p['postimg']."'>".htmlspecialchars($p['body'])."
                        <form action='dry.php?postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                            <input type='submit' name='like' value='Like'>
                            <span>".$p['likes']." likes</span>
                        </form>
                        <hr /></br />
                                ";
                    } else {
                        $posts .="<img src='".$p['postimg']."'>".htmlspecialchars($p['body'])."
                        <form action='dry.php?postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                            <input type='submit' name='unlike' value='Unlike'>
                            <span>".$p['likes']." likes</span>
                        </form>
                        <hr /></br />
                                ";
                    }
                }
            }
?>

<form action="try.php" method="post" class = "forum" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="postbody" rows="4" cols="60" class = "text"></textarea>
         <br />Upload an image:
        <input type="file" name="postimg">
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
</form>
```

Comment: Try using `$_REQUEST` instead of  `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: yeah I've tried that and it didn't change anything

Comment: Then do some debugging , eg : `echo $_POST['post'];`

Comment: try printing the whole request array before the first if,to see what's in there, like this:

     `print_r($_REQUEST);` or `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: I get this : Array ( ), so it's null?

Comment: Let's see the form

Comment: The portion near the bottom is a typo, do you mean that section? You have `if(isset($_FILE['postimg'])){`, you are missing the `S` in `$_FILES`

Comment: yeah it is but I've tried $_FILES and it didn't help, I actually meant to put $_POST and that didn't work either